# TCC Error: index too large

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, raycasting, tcc

I have been playing around with ray-casting and decided to use 3D arrays to make levels, However TCC spits out this:

```
M_MAIN.C:19: error: index too large
```

Is there a limit to how large an array can be?
Code:

```
#define MAP_01_WIDTH 8
#define MAP_01_HEIGHT 8
#define MAP_01_DEPTH 8
#define MAP_01_PLAYER_START_X 2
#define MAP_01_PLAYER_START_Y 2
#define MAP_01_PLAYER_START_Z 2

char MAP_01[MAP_01_WIDTH][MAP_01_DEPTH][MAP_01_HEIGHT] =
{
    { {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1} },
    { {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1} },
    { {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1} },
    { {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1} },
    { {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1} },
    { {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1} },
    { {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1} },
    { {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1} },
    { {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1} }
};
```

Comment: Looks like you have 9 rows of data but have declared only eight, hence the compiler complaint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define the array with size `8x8x8` but initializing it with `9x8x8` elements. Fix the size with:

```
#define MAP_01_WIDTH 9
```

Or better yet, let the compiler calculate that:

```
char MAP_01[][MAP_01_DEPTH][MAP_01_HEIGHT] = {...};
```